# SMART-status: reallocated_sector_ct FAILING_NOW

Tags: hard-drive, arch-linux

On my HDD which I've put in my Synoglogy NAS DS207+ I see this SMART-status:
[image: FAILING_NOW]

Is there any way to fix or circumvent this issue? 
Is there any way to fix this by partitioning (the disk is 1TB)

(If this question should be in AskUbuntu please comment or move)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, the only way to fix this issue is to do a backup and replace this drive. Why do you want to risk data on this drive when clearly there are physical issues already reported by [S.M.A.R.T.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)?

From Wikipedia:

> Reallocated Sectors Count - Potential indicator of imminent
>   electromechanical failure.

And definition:

> Count of reallocated sectors. When the hard drive finds a
>   read/write/verification error, it marks that sector as "reallocated"
>   and transfers data to a special reserved area (spare area). This
>   process is also known as remapping, and reallocated sectors are called
>   "remaps". The raw value normally represents a count of the bad sectors
>   that have been found and remapped. Thus, the higher the attribute
>   value, the more sectors the drive has had to reallocate. This allows a
>   drive with bad sectors to continue operation; however, a drive which
>   has had any reallocations at all is significantly more likely to fail
>   in the near future.[3] While primarily used as a metric of the life
>   expectancy of the drive, this number also affects performance. As the
>   count of reallocated sectors increases, the read/write speed tends to
>   become worse because the drive head is forced to seek to the reserved
>   area whenever a remap is accessed. If sequential access speed is
>   critical, the remapped sectors can be manually marked as bad blocks in
>   the file system in order to prevent their use.

Comment: Also, do this *right now*. Not tomorrow, not in two hours, but now.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks for the worries, the disk is empty already - just trying if I can fix the bad sector or not. If not, I'll trash it.

Comment: It might be still under warranty (they often fail before the 3 years mark). Send it back to the constructor to get a free new one.

Comment: @Kwaio Any source on this?

Comment: It depends on the brand of the disk, but all the disks I have seen failing at home were under warranty (Seagate/western digital). Once you have identified the brand, look in google for "[brand ] warranty return" or something similar. All it will costs are fees to send the package back to the retailer

Comment: Seagate it is, thanks I will look. I removed this disk from TimeCapsule by Apple a while ago because the SMART status failed. I was trying to repair, but I rather send it back or trash it then. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can't influence this in any way. The disk will automatically replace faulty sectors as long as there are spare ones available (how many depends on your drives model and can be found in the spec).

If the number of reallocated sectors does not increase, you might be on the safe side. But better don't count on it and replace the drive as soon as possible or you will risk losing your data.